# How can I download files if there is no SD card?

Tags: sd-card, downloading, images

I have no SD card in my phone. And I would like to know how I can save pictures in a place where I can access them later because I download them on tumblr.

Comment: It would help to know your model at least. Does it have a so-called "internal SD-Card", like the Nexus models do? Then this could be used. If there's no storage available, it's hard to find a place to store stuff. So if the device has a microSD slot, the easiest thing probably is buying a card (class-6 recommended, don't try to save money buying anything below class-4 or you'll regret it). If you're just downloading on-the-fly to xfer stuff to your computer later, see [Sid's answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/48382/16575) below.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you have no SD card, you can use the apps provided by reputed cloud services to store your data. In order to do this, you have to have at least some amount of memory in your device as you have to download them into your phone before you upload them to cloud services. (There are apps that facilitate remote file downloads<sup>1</sup> as well). Some of the best apps out there are listed below.

- [DropBox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dropbox.android&hl=en)
- [Sky Drive](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.skydrive)
- [Google Drive](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.docs)
- Or [search the Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=Cloud%20storage&c=apps) for more apps

With those apps, you can save, view/listen, edit and share the files you have, without keeping them in your mobile device.

---

<sup>1</sup>Remote file downloading allows you to save the files in somewhere without downloading and re-uploading. All you have to do is to paste the file link in the relevant place.

Comment: Dropbox has an automatic picture sync option which uploads new pictures which I find useful.

Answer (score 0):

I use Dropbox with its auto upload pictures option. I can then download them from Dropbox on my PC.

Comment: There are lots of other options to do this too: Google+, Facebook, Carbonite, Lookout. Automatic photo uploads seems to be the new killer function.

Answer (score 0):

Upload to google drive.

download google drive on your device.

Find file in google drive

tap (i) next to file "Download a copy" will dl to internal storage.