# Archiving photos sent to Gmail

Tags: gmail, photos, storage

My only access to computer is my [Samsung epic](http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/cell-phones/SPH-D700ZKASPR) cell phone. My storage is getting full because I take a lot of photos. If I send them to Gmail & archive them. Will this free up some storage space in my phone even though I keep my Gmail app on my phone ?

Answer (score 0):

Short: **Yes**. You can send your photos as email attachments and delete them from your phone. It will free up your phone memory. *But* there are other options which are better than this.

You can **use cloud storage facilities** to back-up your data and access them anytime and anywhere you want. More details about widely used cloud services can be found in **[this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/48382/23379)**.